# Nlog - email logs every x minutes

Tags: c#-4.0, nlog

Is it possible to email logs every x minutes using NLog?. if so, are there any examples.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt It, If I was you I would only email Logs of Error or Fatal level, if you what to email at specific times, just create a simple timer that emails the ErrorLog.txt File every x minutes.

Comment: it is possible to send logs using NLog, but its not ideal for what im trying to do. thanks for your help.