# How to archive logs on a specified number of days/hours?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, archive, nlog

Is this possible in n-log or should a feature request be made if needed. I did take into consideration the question about [logging to emails every x minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531287/nlog-email-logs-every-x-minutes) with no enlightenment.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?: http://nlog-project.org/wiki/File_target#Time-based_file_archival

Comment: @madth3: Similar, but I need to specify the number of days/hours instead of one day or one hour: which is what's specified in the link.